# Refreshing the cache only happens once no matter how many times I try..!! Is IIS caching the response?

Tags: sql-server, caching, iis

We have a cache that is refreshed every time a new ip is added or deleted to the db. The db makes a call the webserver and refreshes the cache.

Here's the url that db is hitting to refresh:

```
 http://webserver1/system/cache/refresh.aspx?cache=ips
```

The first time this request is made, I can see it in the logs. But after that no matter how many times I add or delete ips, I cannot see any new request in the iis logs.

But again if I add an extra parameter to the url, the request appears in the log and cache gets refreshed. So something like

```
http://webserver1/system/cache/refresh.aspx?cache=ips&foo=foo
```

We do not have any output caching enabled on iis. We are using iis 8.5.

Can any one point me where to look at or some reference material?

Comment: Are you sure it is not just that the log is buffered in memory so it takes some time before they show up? Try running "netsh http flush logbuffer" from an elevated command line and then look in the log to see if those are there. It also depends on the status code being returned that the browser might be caching it, try using Fiddler to see if the request is actually made to the server or not, that could likely be the case if it returns headers that allow/enable/request cache in the client.

Comment: @CarlosAguilarMares The request is coming out of the db but the server seems to be ignoring it. I did a trace on the stored procedure and the request is reaching the server. I will try use Fiddler and see if I can find anything. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Chennakrishna, is it possible to use the POST method instead of GET? POST requests won't be cached.

Comment: @DmitryPolyakov That is a neat idea. I will try that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CarlosAguilarMares It seems that msxml3 will spin up an IE process to make that call and that is caching the request rather than iis caching it.